# JQuery JQPrint css

Tags: jquery, jqprint

How can I include an external css file in jqprint? What could be the problem with my code why I can t Hide a simple button using an inline stylesheet with a media which is equal to print? Here is my sample code.

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">

#hide
{
    display:none;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jqprint-0.3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( "#printMe" ).click(function() {
            $('#print').jqprint();

        });
    });
</script>

<div id="header">
    <h1>This is the Header</h1>
</div>

<div id="print"><br />
    <input type="button" id="hide" value="hidden"/>
    <input type="button" id="printMe" value="Print Me"/>
</div>
```

When I just use javascript's window.print, it hides the button with the id hide. What could be the problem ?

Comment: please add jsfiddle to easy. i have not JQPRINT plugins.

Answer (score 0):

> Here is [**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/v6K58/238/)

see this http://jsfiddle.net/v6K58/

```
 $(function() {
        $( "#printMe" ).click(function() {
            $('#header').jqprint();

        });
    });​
```

bold [text print](http://jsfiddle.net/v6K58/1/)

Comment: of course it will be hidden when you print it because it is hidden right from the start. What I want is to hide an element which is visible when I load the page.

Comment: yes you can [add css see this](https://github.com/tanathos/jquery.jqprint/blob/master/jquery.jqprint-0.3.js) u can [try this way](http://jsfiddle.net/v6K58/2/)